# Getting position of char in vector (C++)

Tags: c++, string, vector, char

I am trying to check if char exists in vector of chars, and if so, to get it`s number. I have done the first part (check if char exists):

```
char letter(a);
string word;
vector<char>vWord(word.begin(), word.end());
if(find(vWord.begin(), vWord.end(), letter) != vWord.end()){}
```

But I have no idea how to get the position. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could simply use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) instead, which returns the index

Comment: `int index = std::find(vWord.begin(), vWord.end(), letter) -  vWord.begin();`

Comment: @KarstenKoop: You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the iterator and do some math on it:

```
vector<char>::iterator itr = find(vWord.begin(), vWord.end(), letter);
if(itr != vWord.end())
{
   int index = itr - vWord.begin();
}
```

However do note that `std::string` already has a [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) method.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You already have an iterator pointing to that character (returned by `find`), so you can use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to find the distance:

```
char letter(a);
string word;
vector<char>vWord(word.begin(), word.end());
auto it = find(vWord.begin(), vWord.end(), letter);
if (it != vWord.end())
{
  size_t index = std::distance(vWord.begin(), it);
}
```

For random-access iterators (such as those used by `std::vector`), `std::distance(a, b)` is a constant-time operation and is implemented by doing `b - a`.

Side note: you can do `std::find` and iterator operations on `std::string` directly; it's a perfectly fine container in its own right.

Comment: The age-old using `-` versus `std::distance`.

Comment: You should probably use `auto`, not `size_t`. This probably isn't an issue in the scenario posed by the question, but some uses of `std::distance` can return a negative number, and the `difference_type` of the iterator is probably a signed integer.

Comment: @Xirema In *this* case, `std::distance` cannot possibly return a negative number, and having an index into the container of type other than `size_t` could have its own issues down the road.